# Netlify event body returns '[object object]'

Tags: aws-lambda, netlify

I have an async function like this:

```
async function clicked () {
  
  const response =  await fetch(`http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/hello`, {
    method: 'GET',
     headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({message:'hello'})
  })
}
```

The exports function looks like this

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) =>  {

console.log(event, 'event')
  return {
    statusCode:200,
    
  }
}
```

When I console.log the event, it give me

```
body: '[object Object]'
```

Normally, the 'message hello' should be shown inside the event body. I tried to use JSON.stringify, JSON.parse, but nothing works.

My netlify.toml file looks like this

```
[build]
functions="/functions"
```

The function gets invoked normally and returns status code 200. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Try to parser the body :

```
console.log(JSON.parser(event), 'event')
```

Comment: Good idea, tried that though. It returns "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1".

Comment: Maybe add json() to your res from the server